# I want to generate barcodes in a Word document. How do I do this?

Tags: vb.net, barcode

I have EAN-8 standard barcode information stored in the DB. I am trying to generate a report in MS Word Document format.  The requirement is that I create barcode in the document using the stored info from DB.  I am using VB.net (.NET Framework 2.0).

I did not find any APIs in MSDN? What are the ways to implement this requirement?  Any pointers please.  Are there any samples available?

Answer (score 3):

There may be more sophisticated solutions to your problem but the simple way is to use a **Barcode Font** within your Word document.

If you [search for barcode fonts](http://www.google.com/search?q=barcode%20font) you should find a bunch of fonts including EAN8. In some cases you'll have to pay a licence but I believe there are free versions too.

Also, you'll have to work out how to distribute the font with your product.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the bar code information via a bar code font.  One in particular I've personally used is [WASP](http://www.waspbarcode.com/software/fontware.asp) barcode fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a barcode image using [Barcode.dll barcode component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/barcode/):

```
Dim barcode As BaseBarcode
barcode = BarcodeFactory.GetBarcode(Symbology.EAN8)

barcode.Number = "1234567"
barcode.ChecksumAdd = true

Dim bitmap As Bitmap
bitmap = barcode.Render()

' You can also save it to a file or use to create report
barcode.Save("c:\\barcode.gif", ImageType.Gif)
```

Please note that Barcode.dll is a commercial product I created.

Comment: @hawbsl Hmmm, evertyhing is ok on my side: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.lesnikowski.com/barcode/

Comment: Hello Pawel, Thanks for the info. Sounds interesting.  I shall get in touch with you soon to understand about your product.